# Where can I find an Audio project file from feature film as an example?

Tags: audio, software, editing, tutorial

I'm an independent filmmaker, and I'm trying to improve my sound design skills for my next project. Have any of you come across a post or a website where a sound designer has uploaded an audio project file from a movie? Like a project file for protools, audition, logic, etc? I know this is probably rare, but I'm hoping to see how a mix has been created. The next best thing would be a tutorial that would similarly show this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The mix alone is only a small part of the process: dialogue cleaning, adr, sound design, foley etc.. being the bigger part of the process. a lot of these things are kind of "self explanatory" if you watch a movie that you like (soundwise) and analyze it. you will probably not know if they used 12 or 120 tracks but you can certainly hear that certain dialogies are too clear to have been recorded in that specific location or certain sounds that are too pronounced to have been part of a direct sound recording etc.

i have my doubt about the quality of this video but checkit out

and here
http://www.thebeachhousestudios.com/mixing-sound-for-film-audio-post-production-overview/